# Scrape talent composite ratings from web url

Tags: r, web-scraping

How would I scrape the ratings from the following webpage: https://247sports.com/Season/2019-Football/CollegeTeamTalentComposite/

I tried copying and pasting but that did not work.  I also tried the code

```
Tables <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(css = "table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

but that wasn't successful.  Any ideas???

Comment: The information is not a table. You need to examine the page's source in order to get the correct CSS selector.  Try: `html_nodes(css = "li.rankings-page__list-item")` This will return a list of elements for each row.

Comment: Tried this solution but get the following error: Error in html_table.xml_node(X[[i]], ...) : 
  html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE

Comment: The information is not a table, thus error with `html_table()`. Please go back and accept the answers from your previous questions, this will close out the question and thank the ones who have helped you in the past. If you are still having trouble, I should be able to create a solution later.